# Pyramid route for favicon.ico in url dispatch is found, but not found by traversal at same time

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm working with [the cookbook instructions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/static_assets/files.html#serving-a-single-file-from-the-root) for /favicon.ico and /robots.txt URLs and seeing something strange. I'm adding the routes with `add_route`:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    # ....
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('public', 'public', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('favicon.ico', '/favicon.ico')
    config.add_route('robots.txt', '/robots.txt')
    config.add_route('home','/{id}')  #don't worry about this one
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

and defining the views as like so:

```
@view_config(name='favicon.ico')
def favicon_view(context, request):
    return _fi_response


@view_config(name='robots.txt')
def robotstxt_view(context, request):
    return _robots_response
```

Where `_fi_response` and `_robots_response` are created as per instructions in that link above. Sadly, when I go to one of my pages there is no favicon and going to `localhost:6544/favicon.ico`, it results in a 404. Oddly, when I have all the debugging turned on, I see this:

```
2012-10-13 21:38:50,437 DEBUG [trosted][Dummy-5] route matched for url http://localhost:6544/favicon.ico; route_name: 'favicon.ico', path_info: u'/favicon.ico', pattern: '/favicon.ico', matchdict: {}, predicates: ''
2012-10-13 21:38:50,438 DEBUG [trosted][Dummy-5] debug_notfound of url http://localhost:6544/favicon.ico; path_info: u'/favicon.ico', context: <pyramid.traversal.DefaultRootFactory instance at 0x102b6a7a0>, view_name: u'', subpath: (), traversed: (), root: <pyramid.traversal.DefaultRootFactory instance at 0x102b6a7a0>, vroot: <pyramid.traversal.DefaultRootFactory instance at 0x102b6a7a0>, vroot_path: ()
```

Which makes me think that the favicon is found by one process but not the other. Wondering if anyone has any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue is that you have added a route named "favicon.ico" and you have not attached a view to that route. Thus the log output says a route matched. You used the "name" parameter to `view_config` which is actually matching the "name" concept in traversal. The way to fix this is to use the "route_name" option to `view_config`.

```
@view_config(route_name='favicon.ico')
def favicon_view(request):
    return _fi_response
```

If you didn't have the catchall route `/{id}` stomping all other 1-level-deep urls in your site, you could remove the favicon route and just let traversal handle it with the "name" parameter.

Comment: route_name vs name was the answer. Thanks! (this is for a tiny micro-site so I'm not bothering with traversal and resources).